# Consecutive use of std::list causes crash

Tags: c++, eclipse, stdlist

I have code which is meant to do memory management, but it keeps crashing at a certain point where I remove an object from the 'live' list and place it onto the 'dead' one:

```
class MemoryObject {
private:
    static std::list <MemoryObject *> alive, dead;
    long references;
public:
    MemoryObject() {
        alive.push_back(this);
        references = 0;
    }

    static void deepClean() {
        clean();
        std::list<MemoryObject *>::iterator iterator;
        for(iterator = alive.begin(); iterator != alive.end(); iterator ++) {
            MemoryObject *object = *iterator;
            Log::instance().write(DEBUG_LOG, "\nObject still active at the end of the program, check for memory leaks."
                    "\nSize: %d",
                    alive.size());
            delete object;
        }
        alive.clear();
    }

    void reference() {
        references ++;
    }

    void release() {
        references --;
        if(references <= 0) {
            dead.push_back(this);
            alive.remove(this);
        }
    }

    static void clean() {
        std::list<MemoryObject *>::iterator iterator;
        for(iterator = dead.begin(); iterator != dead.end(); iterator ++)
            delete(&iterator);
        dead.clear();
    }

    ~MemoryObject() {
        clean();
    }
};

std::list <MemoryObject *> MemoryObject::alive, MemoryObject::dead;
```

Eclipse debug shows it failing under release(), always at the second list-related spot - I've tried putting them (`alive.remove(this) and dead.push_back(this)`) in a different order, which changes nothing. Interestingly however, if I place something in-between them, like a printf() statement, it doesn't crash...

Here's where I'm calling it from:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "log/log.hpp"
#include "memory/object.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MemoryObject foo;
    foo.release();
    MemoryObject::deepClean();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `clean` function you have `delete(&iterator)`. That's hardly correct.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the functions.

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: its not really clear what you want to achieve here. The memory of `foo` is already managed automatically and you dont have to do anything extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `clean` function you have:

```
    delete(&iterator);
```

That will compile, but will attempt to delete the iterator itself - which is on the stack (which will crash).

I suspect you wanted:

```
    delete(*iterator);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete an object that was not allocated with new. `MemoryObject foo;`is not allocatetd with new.

Answer (score 0):

You `delete` only what is allocated through `new`.

```
MemoryObject foo;
foo.release();
```

And inside clean

```
for(iterator = dead.begin(); iterator != dead.end(); iterator ++)
        delete(*iterator);  //I am assuming you have * instead of &(which is incorrect as mentioned in another answer).
```

So you are calling `delete()` on something which was not allocated through `new`Try this.

```
MemoryObject *foo=new MemoryObject();
foo->release();
```

EDIT: This will still not work for the below reason.

Inside `clean()` you are deleting element of `dead` which is `this` of the current object.So in short you are doing something like this

```
class A
{
    void delete_this()
    {
        delete(this);
        //At this point "this" is a dangling pointer and you should not use it.
    } 
};
```